# How to Horizontally Align Navigation Bar Button Items - Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, navigationcontroller

I have these two bar buttons in a navigation controller
[image]

They're not exactly horizontally aligned and I'm not sure how to align them.

Here's the code I wrote for the bar button items.

```
navController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: 
.plain, target: nil, action: nil)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Skip", style: 
.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.tintColor = .red
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. One line sets `navController.navigationItem`, the other sets `self.navigationItem`. Those things are unrelated, and the former is very weird. What's going on here?

Comment: if you put your picture in a photo editor, like sketch or PhotoShop and draw a straight line on the middle of the Back button, you will see the two button exactly are in the same position.(this is just optical illusion due to the colour difference, red and blue are the two side of the colour scale, that is why you see difference)